# disable a button in angular when clicked

Tags: angularjs

I found a tutorial where I check the checkbox and the button next to it is disabled

```
<input type = "checkbox" ng-model = "enableDisableButton">Disable Button <br>
<button ng-disabled = "enableDisableButton">Click Me!</button>
```

But I do not want the check box. When the button is clicked, I want it to be disabled. For example, it can only be clicked once. But no check box.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<button ng-disabled = "enableDisableButton" ng-click="enableDisableButton=true">Click Me!</button>
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fnLj28j8/)

Comment: There is already a function on ng-click. The current function is ng-click='startTimer()'

Comment: Please post the actual code you're working with so that we can help.

Answer (score 0):

in your controller create a state which controls the button.

something like

```
$scope.buttonDisabled = false;

$scope.startTimer = function()
{
    $scope.buttonDisabled = true;
    --anything else you need to do
}
```

in your html :

```
<button ng-disabled="buttonDisabled" ngclick="startTimer();" >Click Me!</button>
```

I don't know exactly how you want this to function in the context of your app but this should be enough to get you started. You can modify the method any way you need, maybe pass the state as a parameter should you need that.

**Edit**

modified to reflect the changes asked by OP.
I don't particularly like this naming convention but should work.

Comment: There is already a function on ng-click. The current function is ng-click='startTimer()'

Comment: you can start the timer and disable the button in the same function. So, in that function the first thing you do is disable the button, then do what you need to do next

Comment: There is already a function on ng-click. The current function is ng-click='startTimer() enableDisableButton=true' like this?

Comment: I modified the initial answer to reflect the change